# create variable with a variable number in php

Tags: php

What I am trying to achieve is to create x amount of variables based on an user input.

To explain a bit more, a user would send a int value by a form (method POST). Based on this value (once verified it is an int, safe etc), I want to create the amount of variables. However I can only think in pseudo code but canot find a way to do it.

In the bigger scale of what I am trying to do, arrays only would not work which is why i really need to create variables.
Here is the pseudo code I thought of but which will not work like it is

```
$result = $_POST['result'];
$result_cleaned = $result;
$each_result = 0;
for ($each_result; $each_result <= $result_cleaned; $result_cleaned++){
$variable$result_cleaned = array();
}
```

So if the user type "3" my code should create

```
$variable1
$variable2
$variable3
```

any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need variables like that? It is likely a design issue, if that is necessary for some reason.

Comment: You might want to think through the array-based solution to this again. It would be a lot neater than having hundreds of variables running around.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`extract` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
$result = $_POST['result'];
$result_cleaned = $result;
$each_result = 0;
$variables = [];
for ($each_result; $each_result <= $result_cleaned; $each_result++){
    $variables['variable'.$each_result] = array();
}
extract($variables); // create $variable1, $variable2 ...
```

I corrected the `for` loop as it seems weird to me.

Note that you can also just use the `$variables` array instead of extract the values intot the script.